# Use Yii findAll to return a model w/ all properties

Tags: php, activerecord, yii

I am still new to Yii and wondering how to return JSON from the `$models = MyModel::model()->findAll();`.

Say for example `MyModel` has a relation for `MyChildModels` in a ONE:MANY fashion.

Straight from the Rest example on the Yii site I have:

```
foreach ($models as $model) {
    $rows[] = $model->attributes;
}

$this->_sendResponse(200, CJSON::encode($rows), 'application/json');
```

I get all of the model's attributes but NOT the joined relation attributes.

Similarly, I can change the `$rows` line to be:

```
$rows[] = $model->myChildModels;
```

...and I get all of the `myChildModels` attributes for each model, but not any attributes (as I would expect).

But what I want is the full suite - the `Model` attributes PLUS all of the `myChildModels` and their attributes.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do the same thing with Yii. Here is how I do it.

```
$models = MyModel::model()->findAll();
    if ($models){
    echo CJSON::encode($models);
    }
```

I don't normally sent a JSON header, but you can if you want.

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

for related models try this.

```
foreach ($models as $model) {
        $rows[] = $model->attributes;               
        $rows[] = $model->related->attributes;
    }
```

Comment: I tried that, but I only got the model attributes, not the relationship attributes as well...

Comment: The result of that is that the objects will be as such: `{[Object1],[Related1],[Object2],[Related2],..,[ObjectN],[RelatedN]}` which is not desirable. What I would need is either: `{[Object1 [attributes], [related1attributes]...}` or `{[Object1 all-attributes-with-related],[Object2 all-attributes-with-related]}` if that makes sense

Comment: Your latest idea works if done as follows: `$rows[] = array($myModel, $myModel->relatedModels);`