# Yii CDbCriteria and Model->findAll, how to add custom column?

Tags: php, yii

I have a calendar app in Yii where I store events per user.  I'd like to dynamically build a title for each event.

This code is in my controller:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->select = array('all_day','end','id','start');
$criteria->condition = 'user_id ='.$user->id;
$events = Calendar::model()->findAll($criteria);
foreach($events as $event) {
  $event->title = 'test title';
}
echo CJSON::encode($events);
```

In my Calendar model, I've added a new property called $title:

```
public $title;
```

But then when I go to echo the JSON, title doesn't show up...

```
[{"all_day":false,"end":"-948712553","id":"2","start":"-146154706"}]
```

What do I need to do to add title to the JSON result set?

Comment: so you ultimately want something like this: `{"title":"test title","all_day":false,"end":"-948712553","id":"2","start":"-146154706"}` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because `CJSON::encode` encodes the *attributes* of each model, and *custom properties* are not added to the attributes of the model. The way custom properties are added to the model, this can not be done in a straightforward way.

I did come up with a workaround though taking the hint from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10184668/720508):

```
$events = Calendar::model()->findAll($criteria);
$rows=array();// we need this array
foreach($events as $i=>$event) {
    $event->title = 'test title';
    $rows[$i]=$event->attributes;
    $rows[$i]['title']=$event->title;
}

echo CJSON::encode($rows); // echo $rows instead of $events
```

The code above should work.

Comment: this is adding `title` to the end of each row, but ofcourse you can use some more code to add it to the beginning of each row if you wish.

Answer (score 4):

you can extend your model and provide your new attribute like this:

```
    public function getTitle() {
        return "test title";
    }

    public function getAttributes($names = true) {
        $attrs = parent::getAttributes($names);
        $attrs['title'] = $this->getTitle();

        return $attrs;
    }
```

Comment: but wouldn't this permanently keep that attribute set to 'test title'? How do I set the attribute to something else?

Comment: create a setter such as setTitle($title) function.